# Derive Weierstrass product theorem from Mittag - Leffler theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

This question is from Ponnusamy Silvermann's Complex analysis section Mittag-Leffler Theorem and I am struck on this.

> Derive Weierstrass product theorem from  Mittag-Leffler theorem

I am confused on how I should prove it as Mittag-Leffler theorem guarantees the existence of a meromorphic function which has poles at a sequence ${b_n}$ while Weierstrass theorem is about proving existence of an entire function that has zeroes at a sequence of points.

So, if I take a sequence $a_n$ that has no finite limits points. I am not sure how I can use Mittag-Leffler theorem to prove the existence of an entire function which has zeroes only at $a_n$, in fact I don't have any intution.

Can you please help in proving it.

Comment: If f has a pole of order k at z, then 1\f has a zero of order k at z?

Comment: @jvc I know that. But unable to use it. So,  do you mind outlining a proof?